What is the best way to fill in screw holes on white kitchen cabinets?
I want to relocate the location of my kitchen cabinet knobs, what is the best way I could fill in the old screw holes? Would I just use wood putty and then use white touch-up paint?
Thank you.

It should work.  The problem will be if it stands out or blends in enough to hide.  Screw holes are usually tiny so that helps.  Should try filling a screw hole in a hidden section(sides/inside) before trying.

What are the cabinets made of, painted wood, formica, thermal foil, melamine?

@RMDman It says the following “Door Material: 3/4" Dowel Jointed Hardwoods with Plywood Panels”.

It really depends on the finish (finish can be hard to match) and what the door looks like after the knobs are removed (they may have left an impression in the wood).  It also depends on your tolerance for fixes that may not be perfect—are your eyes gonna be drawn to the fix every time you look at a cabinet?

Yeah, good points; I'm going to test this on one of the holes and see what it looks like.  These are the kitchen cabinets I purchased.
https://americanmadecabinets.com/collections/white-rta-shaker-cabinets/products/wb30-white-rta-shaker-cabinet
I emailed them and they told me the touch-up paint to use for these are the following.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lincoln-Electric-White-Deluxe-Paint-Marker-KH963/205993167

If the cabinets are solid wood, with no covering (e.g. Formica, laminate, etc.), and including painted plywood, you can use wood filler, sand, and then paint.
If the cabinets are made out of any other material, including wood covered by Formica, compressed particleboard, etc. then use screw plugs. They are sold by the bag and in different sizes and materials. I like the ones made out of rubber.

Would plywood panels fall under solid wood category?

Depends on what's on the surface of the plywood.

These are the type of kitchen cabinets that I purchased:  https://americanmadecabinets.com/collections/white-rta-shaker-cabinets/products/wb30-white-rta-shaker-cabinet

I would just white rubber plugs.

I've used sawdust mixed with elmers glue before just making a thick paste.
